# Google seet formula to copy value based on text or pattern match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Google workbook, I have two sheets.
Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. I need to copy a value from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1, if the cell value of Sheet 1 matches **exactly** to the cell value in Sheet 2.

**Sheet 1**

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| sample-topic |  |
| sample---topic-to-read |  |
| this-is--sample-topic |  |
| sample-topic-8888 |  |
| 555-sample-topic |  |
| sample-topic-2 |  |

**Sheet 2**

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| const-text-sample-topic | 1111 |
| const-text-sample---topic-to-read | 2222 |
| const-text-this-is--sample-topic | 3333 |
| const-text-sample-topic-8888 | 4444 |
| const-text-555-sample-topic | 5555 |
| const-text-sample-topic-2 | 6666 |

If the value (*under the **name** column*) in sheet 1 exactly matches the value (*under the **name** column* in sheet 2) then the id value of the corresponding row should be copied to sheet 1.

I have tried to use VLOOKUP with wildcard match, but the strings "sample-topic" and "const-text-sample-topic-8888" both return the same ID value. But infact they are two uniqe strings.

I used the following vlookup formula `=vlookup("*"&A2&"*",sheet2,2,0)` but this does not work and creates duplicates.

Could anyone please help with a formula to find the perfect match between values in google sheets?

***Edit-Update 1*** I had missed a pattern in Sheet 2.

***Edit-Update 2*** Example update.

[image: Image illustration]

Comment: Just remove the wild cards for an exact match

Comment: I had missed a pattern in sheet-2, added that in this question. I hope this changes the situation with regards to the vlookup usage. But thanks for responding.

Comment: care to share a sample sheet with realistic demo data maybe and desired output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture on how to work it out

Comment: Is `Column B in Sheet 1` the expected output? also can you apply your current formula and highlight the failed/wrong_output scenarios...

Comment: yes, column B in sheet 1 is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `XLOOKUP()` like-

```
=XLOOKUP("const-text-"&A2,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B)
```

To make input range dynamic you may use,

```
=MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP("const-text-"&x,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!B:B)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ... But it's not working sir...have updated the question with a screenshot for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(XLOOKUP("const-text-"&A2:A,'sheet2'!A2:A,'sheet2'!B2:B)))
```

OR

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP("const-text-"&A2:A,'sheet2'!A2:A,'sheet2'!B2:B,))
```

Notice the `,` in the end of the second formula